# What is this ODE called and how to solve it

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

As in the title, thanks!

$$g^{\prime\prime}(r)+r^{-1}g^\prime(r)-r^{-2}g(r)=0$$

Comment: @achillehui Yes, thanks! Edited.

Comment: Hint: what is $r\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{d}{dr}g\right)$ ?

Comment: Laplacian of $g(r)$, but about the last term?

Comment: It can be easily rewritten as an [Euler's equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is called an Euler Equation, and can be easily solved by trying $g(r) = r^{ \lambda}$ then solving for the roots of the resulting "characteristic equation" in $\lambda$

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html for more information.